# android - Comparing two very large ArrayLists one of them retrieved from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist

So now I'm trying to display my contacts that only exist in the firebase database 'Users' Table ,

So the first step is to get all my contacts (done perfectly in less than one second) 
and the second one is to retrieve all the users in my database already just to compare the two Arraylists to check if any of my contacts exits in the database or not , if exists then display them (that's the scenario actually)

and I have done that already , but it is a too slow algorithm I'm 100% sure ! ,

if there r two million users in the database , and I have 1000 contacts so 1000 * 2,000,000 !! It is gonna take forever to display my contacts the only exist in firebase database ,

Is there any Solution ?

Here is my code

```
      `
       // this means it will load the whole users from database !
        DatabaseReference  databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                contactsList.clear();

                // this algorithm means that if there is one million records it will loop through 
                 //all of them
                // then add all of them to the list
                // takes lots of time actually :(



                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user  = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    for(Contacts contacts : PhonecontactsList){
                        // if this user phone eqauals the phone we saved in the phone array list
                        if(user.getPhone().equals(contacts.getPhone())){
                            // if the user doesn't exist in the list
                            if (!contactsList.contains(user)) {
                                // add them
                                contactsList.add(new User(
                                        user.getId(),
                                        contacts.getUsername(),
                                        user.imageURL,
                                        user.getStatus(),
                                        user.getPhone(),
                                        user.getTyping_to(),
                                        user.getSearch(),
                                        user.getTimestamp()

                                ));
                            }


                        }
                    }


                }

                UsersAdapter usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(getContext(), contactsList  , false);
                contactsRecycler.setAdapter(usersAdapter);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

`

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetching all of 1 million records from a cloud-hosted database such as Firebase Realtime Database is a very bad idea.  There is no way that transferring all those records over a mobile connection is going to be fast. It could also cost the end user a lot of their data allowance to get that entire set.

If you only need to know which of the database records are in your local set of data, just make a single request for each item in the local set, and show the ones that exist.  You can ignore everything else.